# Python Pandas Add Data with For Loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop

```py
data = pnd.read_csv('csv/pop.csv')
data = data[['date_range','city','sum_pop']]
data['date_range']=pnd.to_datetime(data['date_range'])
data['date_range'] = data['date_range'].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%d.%m.%Y'))

cities_list = nmp.array(data['city'])
cities_list=nmp.unique(cities_list)

for k in cities_list:
    data = data[(data['city'] == k)]
    print(data)
```

Hi,I'm doing a little data analysis with Python.
I want to take the population data according to the city name in the For loop section and then draw the population graphs of each city.I drew the graphics without the for loop at the bottom.I get the following print with "print (data)"

```
date_range                city  sum_pop
0      31.12.2018  Adana(Aladağ)-1757    16653
973    31.12.2017  Adana(Aladağ)-1757    15896
1945   31.12.2016  Adana(Aladağ)-1757    16333
2915   31.12.2015  Adana(Aladağ)-1757    16823
3885   31.12.2014  Adana(Aladağ)-1757    17113
4855   31.12.2013  Adana(Aladağ)-1757    17221
5825   31.12.2012  Adana(Aladağ)-1757    16951
6782   31.12.2011  Adana(Aladağ)-1757    17074
7739   31.12.2010  Adana(Aladağ)-1757    17169
8696   31.12.2009  Adana(Aladağ)-1757    17494
9653   31.12.2008  Adana(Aladağ)-1757    18249
10610  31.12.2007  Adana(Aladağ)-1757    17506
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [date_range, city, sum_pop]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [date_range, city, sum_pop]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [date_range, city, sum_pop]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [date_range, city, sum_pop]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [date_range, city, sum_pop]
Index: []
```

How do I fix this

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: because the first time you say ` data = data[(data['city'] == k)]` you overwrite the full data set with the selection and the other city names are no longer in `data`. Use a different variable name in the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This all can be accomplished more easily with the pandas `.groupby()` method:

```
data = pnd.read_csv('csv/pop.csv')
data = data[['date_range','city','sum_pop']]
data['date_range']=pnd.to_datetime(data['date_range'])
data['date_range'] = data['date_range'].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%d.%m.%Y'))

for city_name, city_data in data.groupby('city'):
    print(city_data)
```

The pandas docs provide a lot of examples in [Group By: split-apply-combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html)